# Bringing a browser to focus in parallel execution selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, sikuli

Can we make sure one particular browser session to bring to front/focus in parallel execution of selenium?
I have a requirement to do keyboard action by pressing enter key , using robot class to handle google payment option in chrome.
And robot key actions are working only when the browser is in focus/front side.

Tried with `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");` but no effect.

Also , tried with `sikuli` , and having the same issue with sikuli too, as it also needs browser to be in focus.
**NOT going for an alternative to use Autoit** , since our project needs to work on both Windows and MAC.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can send keys (Alt + Tab)to switch to the current session of browser since it was just the window in focus and then moved to state of being not focused on.
Here is the code sample in Java

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.ENTER)).build().perform();
```